# Performance evaluation of nested for loops in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I've a doubt about the following code in connection with performance. For me both look same. But some says they are different. But I didn't get any proper explanation.

Do you have an idea about it?

**Case 1 :**

```
for ( int x ; x < LENGTH ; x++ )
   for ( int y ; y < LENGTH ; y++ )
       arr[x+y*rowLength] = arr[x+y*rowLength]<<2;
```

**Case 2 :**

```
for ( int y ; y < LENGTH ; y++ )
   for ( int x ; x < LENGTH ; x++ )
       arr[x+y*rowLength] = arr[x+y*rowLength]<<2;
```

Comment: Why don't you compile them and find out, for yourself?

Comment: Look up row-major versus column-major indexing

Comment: If one is faster it'll be the second one since it accesses consecutive  elements and is thus more likely to find these elements in the cache. Whether it's actually faster depends on the size of `rowLength`.

Comment: +1 for testing it out yourself. Make a driver and make a really big matrix (or many really small ones ((or both))!

Comment: What's the meaning of  `<<2;`

Answer (score 3):

It is about locality of reference, and cache memory. As a mental exercise, one can conceive of instances where "arr" is small enough to fit in a cache line and there is no difference in speed. And then there are cases where arr is large enough that it will differ. But nothing beats actually testing it. Especially since cache is a platform dependent issue.

The question, as worded, leaves an important variable undefined, that is LENGTH. For this question, LENGTH of 10,000,000 may yield a performance difference, where LENGTH of 16 may not.

Notice, I left the exercise up to you to figure out which is faster.

PS: Compilers can perform an optimization called loop unrolling. It is possible that smart compilers can determine that a nested loop can be unrolled, but I'd guess that typically, only the outer will be unrolled. Either way, depending on how you write the above code, you can affect how well the compiler can optimize the final instructions. But that is probably beside the point, for this question, since this is likely in the context of a computer science class on computer architecture.

Comment: thank you very much. your answer helped me to understand about computer science. thanks mrjoltcola again